# Ubuntu Frozen every time when Memory usage over 80%

Tags: performance, ram, swap

Ubuntu Frozen every time when Memory usage over 80%,

It seems that the system hangs due to a load of disk IO -
the screen is frozen and the only thing I can see is the indicator LED of disk keeping light on.

I've already set swappiness to 1, and this issue had bugged me since 12.10

Is there any configuration I can do to fix the problem ? Or I can only upgrade my RAM size?

And in my experience Windows only freezes when ram usage is over 95%.

If I set `sudo swapoff -a` the laggy issue is still there, maybe a little bit improved at least I can do some input, but the disk IO is still abnormally frequent, the whole system is frozen from time to time.

Comment: That sounds very much like a swap issue. How exactly did you set swappiness to 1? Can you confirm that the machine is _not_ swapping when you see these symptoms? Check with `free`.

Comment: @terdon I set it by `sudo sysctl vm/swappiness=1` and `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` output is 1.

Comment: @terdon I guess you are right, swap is used when the RAM over 80%. So how can I set the swappiness correctly.

Comment: @terdon However if I set `sudo swapoff -a` the laggy issue is still  there, maybe a little bit improved at least I can do some input, but the disk IO is still abnormally frequent, the whole system is frozen from time to time.

Comment: Can you run `iotop` and `dstat` to figure out what process is doing IO?

Comment: Setting swappiness to 1 will lower the tendency for it to swap not raise it. So if you are having issues I would set it back to normal (60), then see if there is still an issue.

Comment: you might consider installing zram-config although it is a swap file in RAM, it is compressed and might make the difference. Sure did on that netbook I had. Another thing to consider is adding vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 to /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: @Sneetsher Like my CPU and GPU info?

Comment: @bain Mostly is Chrome, but actually everything is consuming the IO; `iotop` shows that even though the DISK READ/WRITE is practically slow, like  hundreds Kb/s, the percentage of IO is mostly 98% or higher.

Comment: @Sneetsher GPU is Intel HD 3000 which integrated with my i5 processor, and RAM is one 2G and one 4G, 1333Hz

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? If you are on pre-14.04 then you could try upgrading to 14.04. A newer kernel might resolve any IO bug issues.

Answer (score 0):

There might be Some problem Check and go through these process.

#### CPU Heat,

**Note:-**Go to your BIOS Settings and Monitor your CPU Temperature. The Temperature should be 40 to 50. If you are getting more then this then use CPU Thermal paste to cool your CPU Temperature.

#### HDD Sata cable

**Note:-** There should be IO Error change your HDD Sata Cable.

It might not be compatible with 2GB or 4GB of RAM. Remove 2GB RAM from your computer and tried only on 4GB RAM with boot up your computer.

It will solved your problem

Comment: I did HDD test using MHDD, but there's no obvious bad sector in my disk, and CPU's temperature is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in one of the RAM sticks.

I have had this problem when one of my RAM sticks is in bad condition and thanks to it, it does not allow me to use over 75% of the ram stick.

Comment: I did Mem test several times, and the results are all green.

Comment: Have you done HDD test as well? You can do a health test with smart tools. Also you would want to check the I/O's of the disk when the computer is running. You can check the I/O's of the disk with IOTop utility.

Comment: I used MHDD to do the Disk check, no bad sector.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement that you have had this problem since 12.10 gives me some clue as to the age of the hardware. The most likely problem IMHO is failed or failing sectors on the hard drive under the swap partition. You shouldn't have to reduce swappiness to get good performance. Add the output of `free -m` and I may change my answer as 6GB of RAM should be more than ample for most needs.

Comment: now I totally disabled the swap, the problem is still there; and my HDD is fine according to the report of MHDD;

Comment: Someone in IRC told me the problem might be caused by the shared memory of intel HD 3000, so I switch to my AMD Radeon GPU, situation did imporve a little bit, but I don't wanna use the AMD GPU which is poor supported in KDE, so is there any other solutions?

Comment: Can you review your log files and see if there's anything that might give us a clue there?